# Swift 2.0: Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of

Tags: macos, swift, key-value-coding

I am converting an app from Objective-C to Swift 2.0 and while converting an `NSView`-subclass, I am getting an error while trying to store a `weak` back-reference from a `CALayer` to the `ActionViewItemInternal` which is needed so that the layer drawing code can access the item data.  I want to use a `weak` reference in order to avoid a retain-cycle (item object retains layer so layer needs a weak reference back to the item object).

```
class WeakReference {
    weak var reference: AnyObject?

    init(reference: AnyObject) {
        self.reference = reference
    }
}

class ActionView: NSView {

    // Used to store an item in ActionView.items
    private class ActionViewItemInternal {
        var actionViewItem: ActionViewItem
        var layer: CALayer
        ...

        init(withItem actionViewItem: ActionViewItem) {
            self.actionViewItem = actionViewItem
            let layer = CALayer()
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // other init and error here:
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            layer.setValue(value: WeakReference(reference: self), forKey: "ActionViewItem")
            self.layer = layer
        }

    }

    var items: [ActionViewItem] = [ActionViewItem]()
    ...
}
```

Where `ActionItemView` is defined as:

```
@objc protocol ActionViewItem {
    var name: String { get set }
    var icon: NSImage { get set }
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
ActionView.swift:73:19: Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(value: WeakReference, forKey: String)'
```

Xcode version: Xcode 7.0 beta 1.  Deployment targets tried: 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11.

**EDIT**: I have tried using `NSValue`, as per @rickster's suggestion, but the error remains:

```
layer.setValue(value: NSValue(nonretainedObject: self), forKey: "ActionViewItem")

ActionView.swift:72:19: Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(value: NSValue, forKey: String)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setValue(_:forKey:)` method requires an ObjC object for the value — you're passing an instance of a pure Swift class. If you make your `WeakReference` class either annotated with `@objc` or inherit from `NSObject` that call should succeed.

However, you don't need your own class for this purpose anyway... The `NSValue` method [`valueWithNonretainedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithNonretainedObject:) does the same thing.

---

Oh, and on closer inspection: you're using an extra argument label in your call. It should be like `setValue(myvalue, forKey: mykey)`.

Comment: I did consider that and had already tried that (I removed that detail from the question for some stupid reason).  Anyway I have just tried both approaches (`@objc class WeakReference` and using `NSValue(nonretainedObject: self)`) and I get the same error.

Comment: Yep; that was all it was.  Using `setValue(value, forKey:key)` works.  Many thanks and thanks for the tip about `NSValue` (after all these years I have never known about that use of `NSValue`).